# How to count " in the string?

Tags: r, string

I have some strings which contain the symbol " Now I would like to count it. But str_count did not work. Could anyone tell me how can I count this symbol? Thank you

Comment: `str_count(mystring, "\"")`, this works? you need to escape it with \.

Comment: @RLave it works thank you. Could you turn it into an answer? Then I can accept it.